# Why does Apache Spark read unnecessary Parquet columns within nested structures?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

My team is building an ETL process to load raw delimited text files into a Parquet based "data lake" using Spark. One of the promises of the Parquet column store is that a query will only read the necessary "column stripes".

But we're seeing unexpected columns being read for nested schema structures.

To demonstrate, here is a POC using Scala and the Spark 2.0.1 shell:

```
// Preliminary setup
sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

// Create a schema with nested complex structures
val schema = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("F1", IntegerType),
    StructField("F2", IntegerType),
    StructField("Orig", StructType(Seq(
        StructField("F1", StringType),
        StructField("F2", StringType))))))

// Create some sample data
val data = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize(Seq(
        Row(1, 2, Row("1", "2")),
        Row(3, null, Row("3", "ABC")))),
    schema)

// Save it
data.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("data.parquet")
```

Then we read the file back into a DataFrame and project to a subset of columns:

```
// Read it back into another DataFrame
val df = spark.read.parquet("data.parquet")

// Select & show a subset of the columns
df.select($"F1", $"Orig.F1").show
```

When this runs we see the expected output:

```
+---+-------+
| F1|Orig_F1|
+---+-------+
|  1|      1|
|  3|      3|
+---+-------+
```

But... the query plan shows a slightly different story:

The "optimized plan" shows:

```
val projected = df.select($"F1", $"Orig.F1".as("Orig_F1"))
projected.queryExecution.optimizedPlan
// Project [F1#18, Orig#20.F1 AS Orig_F1#116]
// +- Relation[F1#18,F2#19,Orig#20] parquet
```

And "explain" shows:

```
projected.explain
// == Physical Plan ==
// *Project [F1#18, Orig#20.F1 AS Orig_F1#116]
// +- *Scan parquet [F1#18,Orig#20] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/stephenp/data.parquet, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<F1:int,Orig:struct<F1:string,F2:string>>
```

And the INFO logs produced during execution also confirm that the Orig.F2 column is unexpectedly read:

```
16/10/21 15:13:15 INFO parquet.ParquetReadSupport: Going to read the following fields from the Parquet file:

Parquet form:
message spark_schema {
  optional int32 F1;
  optional group Orig {
    optional binary F1 (UTF8);
    optional binary F2 (UTF8);
  }
}

Catalyst form:
StructType(StructField(F1,IntegerType,true), StructField(Orig,StructType(StructField(F1,StringType,true), StructField(F2,StringType,true)),true))
```

According to the [Dremel paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36632.pdf) and the [Parquet documentation](http://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/), columns for complex nested structures should be independently stored and independently retrievable.

Questions:

1. Is this behavior a limitation of the current Spark query engine? In other words, does Parquet support optimally executing this query, but Spark's query planner is naive?
2. Or, is this a limitation of the current Parquet implementation?
3. Or, am I not using the Spark APIs correctly?
4. Or, am I misunderstanding how Dremel/Parquet column storage is supposed to work?

Possibly related: [Why does the query performance differ with nested columns in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622787/why-does-the-query-performance-differ-with-nested-columns-in-spark-sql)

Comment: It is a Spark query engine issue.

Comment: @LostInOverflow, do you know if this is in the Spark issue tracker? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel

Comment: It appears that Parquet should support this scenario according to @julien-le-dem https://twitter.com/J_/status/789584704169123841

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16578 solves the problem.

Comment: @GauravShah, looking forward to seeing this, hopefully in 2.3. Will try and create/mark this as the accepted answer once available in a production release.

Comment: A small update-- the patch is slowly progressing through the Spark development process. Now maybe targeting 2.4 per this patch: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16578

Comment: An update. The previous PR has been closed without resolution and a new simplified PR has been opened. Track the new one here: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/21320

Comment: 2.4.0 appears to fix this problem. I'll see if I can test the fix and then write up the answer.

Comment: Update: 2.4.0 does not seem to fix this problem. The F2 column is still read even though it is not specified in the projection.

Comment: did you turn on the sql flag to enable this optimization ?  2.4.0 seems to fix it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed since Spark 2.4.0. This applies to struct as well as array of structs.

Before Spark 3.0.0:

Set `spark.sql.optimizer.nestedSchemaPruning.enabled` to `true`

See related Jira here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4502

After Spark 3.0.0:

`spark.sql.optimizer.nestedSchemaPruning.enabled` now default is `true`

Related Jira here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29805

Also related SO question: [Efficient reading nested parquet column in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331007/efficient-reading-nested-parquet-column-in-spark)

Answer (score 5):

It's a limitation on the Spark query engine at the moment, the relevant JIRA ticket is below, spark only handles predicate pushdown of simple types in Parquet, not nested StructTypes

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17636

Comment: Limitations in predicate push-down shouldn't affect projections. Problem can be related but not the same.

Comment: Sorry I used the word predicate in my answer but the linked JIRA ticket title is "Parquet filter push down doesn't handle struct fields"

Comment: Not sure this is the answer, but will take a look. The OP doesn't have a filter and so predicate pushdown shouldn't apply.